# modelling a resonator in simulink

Tags: simulink

I have been trying to model the Fabry-Perot resonator in simulink. I am not sure if it is right to choose simulink for this task but I have been getting some results, at least. However, I have been also getting an error of algebraic loop when I use a different pair of coupling/reflection parameters. It says,

"Simulink cannot solve the algebraic loop containing
'jblock_multi_MR/Meander2b/Subsystem3/Real-Imag to Complex' at time
6.91999999999991 using the LineSearch-based algorithm due to one of the
following reasons: the model is ill-defined i.e., the system equations do
not have a solution; or the nonlinear equation solver failed to converge
due to numerical issues.
 To rule out solver convergence as the cause of this error, either
     a) switch to TrustRegion-based algorithm using
         set_param('jblock_multi_MR','AlgebraicLoopSolver','TrustRegion')
     b) reducing the VariableStepDiscrete solver RelTol parameter so that
     the solver takes smaller time steps.
 If the error persists in spite of the above changes, then the model is
 likely ill-defined and requires modification."

Changing the solver does not help. As a note, I implemented the system in terms of electric fields and complex signals naturally.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic solution for solving algebraic loop issues, as these issues tend to be very model-dependent. Here are a few pointers though:

- [What are algebraic loops in Simulink and how do I solve them?](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-16V6S/)
- [How can I resolve algebraic loops in my Simulink model in Simulink 6.5 (R2006b)](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-2S1NR3/index.html?solution=1-2S1NR3)?
- [Algebraic Loops](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/simulating-dynamic-systems.html#f7-19688) in the Simulink documentation

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854981/resolving-problems-with-algebraic-loops-in-simulink-models) to a similar question on SO, with some suggestions for breaking the loop.